# screen space reflection always gives dQ.z

Tags: algorithm, graphics, 3d, render, vulkan

I have implemented [this tutorial](http://casual-effects.blogspot.com/2014/08/screen-space-ray-tracing.html) in Vulkan but I did not get expected result, then I realized in my shader I always have a zeroed dQ.z, I do not have any idea why this is happening, [this](https://github.com/Hossein-Noroozpour/vulkust/blob/54f85278820e2185f7d61f843aa1c1964706a4e8/vulkust/src/vulkan/shaders/deferred.frag#L100) is my messy, debugging, unoptimized implementation.

So, do you have any idea what is wrong?

This is my GLSL code

```
vec3 dir = normalize(p - vpos); // world-space direction
if(is_zero(dir.z)) {
    return false;
}
vec3 tmpv3 = dir * dis + vpos;
if(tmpv3.z < scene_ubo.s.camera.position_far.w) {
    dis = abs((scene_ubo.s.camera.position_far.w - vpos.z) / dir.z);
    if(dis < SMALL_EPSILON) {
        return false;
    }
    tmpv3 = dir * dis + vpos;
} else if (tmpv3.z > scene_ubo.s.camera.near_reserved.x) {
    dis = abs((scene_ubo.s.camera.near_reserved.x - vpos.z) / dir.z);
    if(dis < SMALL_EPSILON) {
        return false;
    }
    tmpv3 = dir * dis + vpos;
}
const vec3 end = tmpv3;

const mat4 proj = mat4(
    half_screen_width, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, -half_screen_height, 0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
    half_screen_width, half_screen_height, 0.0, 1.0
    ) * scene_ubo.s.camera.projection; // Vulkan form of projection

const vec4 h0 = proj * vec4(vpos, 1.0); // vpos is view-space-position (view * position)
const vec4 h1 = proj * vec4(end, 1.0);

const float k0 = 1.0 / h0.w;
const float k1 = 1.0 / h1.w;

const vec3 q0 = vpos * k0;
const vec3 q1 = end * k1;

const vec2 p0 = h0.xy * k0;
const vec2 p1 = h1.xy * k1;

vec4 tmpv4 = vec4(p1 - p0, q1.z - q0.z, k1 - k0);
if(is_zero(tmpv4.x) && is_zero(tmpv4.y)) {
    return false;
}
float endx = screen_width;
bool permute = false;
{
    vec2 ad = abs(tmpv4.xy);
    float coef;
    if(ad.x > ad.y) {
        coef = 1.0 / ad.x;
    } else {
        endx = screen_height;
        permute = true;
        tmpv4.xy = tmpv4.yx;
        coef = 1.0 / ad.y;
    }
    tmpv4 *= coef;
}
const vec4 dpqk = tmpv4;
vec4 pqk = vec4(permute? p0.yx: p0, q0.z, k0);
pqk += dpqk * 0.2;

float prev_z_max_estimate = pqk.z / pqk.w; // I think this is better than vpos.z (?)
float ray_z_max = prev_z_max_estimate, ray_z_min = prev_z_max_estimate;
float scene_z_max = ray_z_max + 10000;
const float z_thickness = 0.1;

float step_index = 0;
for(;
    (step_index < steps) &&
        (pqk.x < endx && pqk.x > 0.0) && // debug
        !is_zero(scene_z_max) &&
        ((ray_z_max < (scene_z_max - z_thickness)) || (ray_z_min > scene_z_max));
    ++step_index, pqk += dpqk
) {
    ray_z_min = prev_z_max_estimate;
    ray_z_max = -abs((dpqk.z * 0.5 + pqk.z) / (dpqk.w * 0.5 + pqk.w));
    prev_z_max_estimate = ray_z_max;
    if (ray_z_min > ray_z_max) {
        float tmp = ray_z_min;
        ray_z_min = ray_z_max;
        ray_z_max = tmp;
    }
    // todo it can be replaced with something much better
    hituv = (permute? pqk.yx: pqk.xy) *  deferred_ubo.s.pixel_step.xy;
    hituv.y = 1 - hituv.y;
    if(hituv.x < 0.0 || hituv.x > 1.0 || hituv.y < 0.0 || hituv.y > 1.0) {
        return false;
    }
    scene_z_max = -abs((scene_ubo.s.camera.view * vec4(texture(position, hituv).xyz, 1.0)).z);

}
return (ray_z_max >= scene_z_max - z_thickness) && (scene_z_max >= ray_z_min);
```

This is mostly like the original code, except I use the world-space position instead of the zbuffer of camera-space.

Comment: please provide a minimal verifiable example, all your code should be put here, not exernally linked to on github.  In this case, your sharer code might be enough.

Comment: I do not understand the reason. My code is completely permanent, It will not change. It is pointing to the specific commit. It is separately describing problem, there is almost no need so see anywhere else in the code.

Comment: Ten years from now github could go down, you could delete your account, github could be blocked in some country, or the directory for your code could be changed.  It doesn't matter if *you* know something will never change, we need to the code here because its the same policy for everyone.  Regardless, this is the communities policy, not mine.